# Rational points and Tesla cards

Tags: elliptic-curves, rational-points, nt.number-theory

I'm rapidly approaching 300,000 curves in my ongoing search for Mordell curves of rank >=8.

Currently I'm finding that I have a bottleneck in the code that locates rational points on these curves.

In my ongoing search for efficiency I'm looking around for alternatives to Stoll's wonderful Ratpoints library, which has served me very well up to now.

I did note that Nvidia have recently released the K20X Tesla card and I wanted to ask if anyone had successfully used these cards, or similar, for this type of work.

Kevin.

EDIT:

I've broken the 300,000 barrier as of 21/12/12 with 302974 curves in our capture range.

Comment: What method are you using for your search?

Comment: Hi John,  there's a brief outline here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/107719/
Right now I have around 6*10^8 curves in my logs.  As you can probably guess, that represents a lot of ratpoints time.

Comment: CUDA is awesome.

Comment: Cuda IS awesome,  but this is not appropriate for this site.